# I need someone to convert web.config to .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, web-config, code-conversion

Hello can anyone convert web.config to .htaccess ? from the code bellow ? i need someone to do this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 9">
                    <match url="^([^/]+)/?$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="chat.php?page={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="RequestBlockingRule1" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="192.95.42.181" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="AbortRequest" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: "i need someone to do this", this is what consultants are for ;-)

Comment: Maybe you should pay someone to do it then.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ chat.php?page=$1
Deny From 192.95.42.181
```